# Calculate Running Total in asp.net Gridview

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

i would like to calculate running total in gridiview using javascript or any other method just to calculate the total hours and the grand total hours as users keying in the numbers.  So here is how my current gridview look like
[image]

i want to calculate the running total as users key in the number as shown in the green highlighted color.

```
<div>
      <asp:GridView ID="grvTest" runat="server"
        ShowFooter="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333"
        GridLines="None" OnRowDeleting="grvStudentDetails_RowDeleting">
        <Columns>

          <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="Row ID" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server">
                <%--<asp:ListItem Value="G">test1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="P">test2</asp:ListItem>--%>
              </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>          
          </asp:TemplateField>


          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Day1">
            <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:TextBox ID="txtDay1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>

          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Day2">
            <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:TextBox ID="txtDay2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>


           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Total">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

          <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
      </asp:GridView>

       GRAND TOTAL:
      <asp:Label ID="lblGrandTotal" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using a query like below to fetch data from database and binding it to your grid.

```
SELECT ID, NAME, HOURS1, HOURS2 FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

You can updated this query to have a new column to calculate your totals.

```
SELECT ID, NAME, HOURS1, HOURS2, HOURS1 + HOURS2 AS TOTAL FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

If this is not the case then please share how you are fetching and filling data into grid. So that I can suggest your more relevant solution.

Comment: i am just trying to calculate the running total as users key in the hours.  If you look at image i posted.. you will see the total hours and the grand total hours are calculated as soon as the user key in the numbers

Comment: add an onchange event like below:-

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDay1"  onTextChanged="return myscript();"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

and in this script update totals column.

Comment: below where? i don't see it

Comment: please see my comment, I have updated it with a sample code.